# matching the pattern to a regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to match following pattern

```
(any word string)/(any word string)Model(any word string)/(any word string)
```

example to match

```
abc/pqrModellmn/xyz
kfkf/flfk/jgf/lflflflMModelkfkfkf/kfkfk
```

etc.
I tried something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\D*\\\D*Model\D*\\");
Matcher m =  p.matcher(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("The match is:" + m.find());
```

Answer (score 2):

- `\` is used as escape sequence for Java string literal, so escape it.
- You should use `/`, not `\`, to match `/`.

Try this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class Test {
    static class Hoge {
        public String getAbsolutePath() {
            return "abc/pqrModellmn/xyz";
            //return "kfkf/flfk/jgf/lflflflMModelkfkfkf/kfkfk";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Hoge fileEntry = new Hoge();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\D*/\\D*Model\\D*/\\D*");
        Matcher m =  p.matcher(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("The match is:" + m.find()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In regex word is captured by `\w`, so I have slightly different regex

```
\w+/\w+Model\w+/\w+
```

Your final code will look like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String rx = "\\w+/\\w+Model\\w+/\\w+";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rx);
    Matcher m =  p.matcher(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());

    System.out.println("The match is:" + m.find());
}
```